# Converting UTC string into NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a date-time string returned by the server in UTC format: 2015-04-21T00:54:46.469Z

I am trying to convert this into NSDate. The code is:

```
NSString *dateString = @"2015-04-21T00:54:46.469Z";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-DDThh:mm:ss.sZ"];
NSDate *locationDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

The value of `locationDate` is nil after executing this

Comment: [Consult the spec.](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
```

or

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
```

Any way, `T` must be in quotes. It seems to be a bug in Apple.

Comment: No. DO NOT use the first option. Do not escape the `Z` in the format string. You will get the wrong results.

Comment: And quoting the `T` is not a bug. You quote it so it is treated as a literal and not a format specifier.

Comment: Agree with @rmaddy. Was wondering why my code output wrong dates and that was why.